# LXD to create/use a Windows 2008 R2 or better server

Tags: windows, lxd

I read in the release docs that Windows is supported as a guest OS.  Is there some docs on how to do this with LxD?  I did some googling and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to find anything about running windows in an LXC container.  However, there is a windows client for managing LXD, which might be what you're seeing?

> The goal of LXC is to create an environment as close as possible to a
>   standard Linux installation but without the need for a separate
>   kernel.

For this reason, I don't think you're going to see any Windows containers running on LXC/LXD, ever.  It goes against the idea of a lightweight, use the resources direct, mentality that LXC stands for.